# What is the better way to avoid using global variables in Android?

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns

To my knowledge, to use global variable can make code smell bad because of its tight coupling or the problem of testing.

And in my situation, I want to use some objects with **IOC/DI** and these objects might be dependent **within any of the activities of fragments**.
So I make a class named **Global** and put **static variables**.

```
public class Global {

    private static ConvertStrategy convertStrategy;
    private static EntityController entityController;

    public static void init(ConvertStrategy convertStrategy, EntityController entityController){
        Global.convertStrategy = convertStrategy;
        Global.entityController= entityController;
    }

    public ConvertStrategy getConvertStrategy(){
        return convertStrategy;
    }

    public EntityController getEntityController (){
        return entityController;
    }
}
```

Then I can init it in the MainActivity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);


    Global.init(new OfflineConvertStrategy() , new OfflineController()); 
    ...
    ...
}
```

So obviously now I'm using Offline algorithm, then other days I can create other type of strategy or controller for online version without changing codes within any dependency to fragments or activities, this is how IOC/DI benefits me.

Sorry for my bad description, hope this image concretize it:

[image: Dependencies]

But when the IOC/DI **object amount growth up**, I feel it's start hard to maintain.

For example ...

```
    public class Global {
    public static Resources resources;
    public static DateConvertStrategy dateConvertStrategy;

    private static MemberController memberController;
    private static ProjectSearcher projectSearcher;
    private static OfficeController officeController;
    private static EntityController<Project> projectController;
    private static EntityController<IssueType> issuetypeController;
    private static EntityController<Issue> issueController;
    private static EntityController<IssueComment> issueCommentController;
    private static EntityController<Timeline> timelineController;
    private static EntityController<MemberIdCardModel> memberIdCardController;
    private static EntityController<TodoTask> todotaskController;
    ...
    ...
}
```

I think somehow I overdosed using IOC/DI and global variables...

Please share your idea.

Comment: Use `Shared Preferences`

Comment: I don't know how to use shared preference to do this, could u give an example?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Comment: SharedPreferences don't do what you want-  they're just a quick way to write data to disk without dealing with Java's horrible file IO.  What you want is a DI library like Dagger or Butterknife.

Comment: thanks for guiding, I will take a look both frameworks.